# How to get cucumber scenario.getName into Zalenium dashboard?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, zalenium

I´m currently integrating my cucumber jvm/selenium project with zalenium.
It´s easy and everything works like charm, but only one little exception.
When driver is instantiated for zalenium, I send desired capabilities like:

desiredCapabilities.setCapability("build","My release name");
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("name","My test name");

And zalenim dashboard reflects this data ok.

But....how cand I send my dynamic cucumber scenario name to this capabilities? It´s possible???

I dont know how can I do this, because at the time of desiredcapabilities definition, cucumber scenarios are not parsed yet and scenario.getName() is always null, and I cant find a way to overwrite de default zalenium scenario name with this value.....

For example, to set final tests status in dashboard, zalenium uses sendCookie to change this vaue, but i cant find any similar for test name.

May appear a silly question, and I´m sure that has a silly answer... :D

Some help??

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by instantiating your browser in Cucumber Before hook and then passing the name to DesiredCapabilities